# ASP.NET/JavaScript: How to surround an auto generated JavaScript block with try/catch statement

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, devexpress, try-catch

In the **Script documents** that asp.net automatically generates how can I surround the whole generated scripts with `try/catch` statement to avoid `'Microsoft JScript Compilation error'`
**My issue is**: i got a DevExpress control `(ASPxGridView)` that added and set-up in run time, since i activated the grouping functionality in the grid I still get JS error says `';'` expected whenever i use (click) on one of grouping/sorting abilities, I activated `script Debugging for IE`, in the JS code turns out that there is no missing `';'` and once i click `ignore` for the error msg that VS generates every thing works fine, and surly end-user can't `see` this msg so i figured out if i try/catch the script that may help avoid this error.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You may handle the [window.onerror](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/error2.shtml) event and return true in this event handler.  We would also appreciate this greatly if you post a separate bug report showing how to reproduce this issue.  We will surely fix it.